# Conditional in Docker argument in Bash

Tags: bash, docker

In my bash file I've something like this

```
docker run -d \
  --network=host \
  --name my-service \
  --log-driver="$LOGGING" \
  if [[ "$LOGGING" == 'splunk' ]]; then
    echo "--log-opt tag={{.ImageName}}/{{.Name}}/{{.ID}} \\";
    echo "--log-opt env=NODE_ENV \\";
  fi
```

But shellcheck complains by showing the following result. Any idea?
 https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC1089

Comment: Is your intent for the docker command to result in either having or not-having those two `--log-opt` flags?

Comment: Yes correct. It is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build the argument list first (in an array), *then* call `docker`. This has the additional benefit of getting rid of the ugly line continuation characters.

```
docker_opts=(
    -d
    --network=host
    --name my-service
    --log-driver="$LOGGING"
    --log-opt="$log_opt"
)

if [[ $LOGGING == splunk ]]; then
    docker_opts+=(
        --log-opt "tag={{.ImageName}}/{{.Name}}/{{.ID}} \\"
        --log-opt "env=NODE_ENV \\"
    )
fi

docker run "${docker_opts[@]}"
```

The main idea, though, is to keep the conditional code as small as possible and keep it separate from the unconditional code.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use `$(if ..; then ...; fi)`:

```
docker run -d \
  --network=host \
  --name my-service \
  --log-driver="$LOGGING" \
  $(if [[ "$LOGGING" == 'splunk' ]]; then
    echo "--log-opt tag={{.ImageName}}/{{.Name}}/{{.ID}}"
    echo "--log-opt env=NODE_ENV"
  fi)
```

Comment: This approach doesn't work either because it create a docker run command which in case that if is false doesn't add any next commands. I mean that command should have appended the name of the image.

Comment: @Mazzy: Have you tested it?